# Why must a user be an admin to add a tab?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to add a tab without being an admin of a page. I have an app, I want users to be able add and open the app from a tab. I figured all I would need was

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=1234567890&redirect_uri=https://myiframelocation.site.com

But this always comes up with, `You must be the admin of at least one Facebook Page to perform the requested action.`

Comment: what do you mean "add"? if you add the page to one of your pages, all users will be able to access it ... also, users can add the app to the pages which they admin

Comment: yeah I am getting confused here. What I want is the app to be added to the boomarks/apps dashboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That [dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/) is only for adding an application(app_id) to a facebook page, not personal(individual) timeline/profile.

If you check the documentation you can see that the dialog that comes up asks you to choose [Facebook pages](https://www.facebook.com/help?page=255100294550008) that you want to add the app to, hence you need to be an admin of atleast one facebook page to be able to add the app.

Comment: ok, further reading proves that "Once a user starts using your app, we create a bookmark" so the bookmark can't be "installed" it just appears when a user accepts your app?

Comment: ok, so I have a boog standard heroku app. apps.facebook.com/mymenutest if I login as it says, why does this not add a bookmark?

Comment: bookmarks is an intelligent list, and they are ordered according to how often you use the app, if you go into this link https://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/apps then you should be able to see your app, if you don't see it then there is something wrong with the way you added the app, in that case show some code.

Comment: If I use the name sapce version it does not add. If I use http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=135578799905375 it does

Comment: is it joe takeaways that you want to add? when i go to the link in your comment the app doesn't ask me for anything(and bookmark is also not added). show the code that you are using please, what documentation are you following?

Comment: Actually it's completely random. However in essence you are correct. Thx

Comment: There should be a [F]login. This is the stock free Heroku page.

Comment: yes for your question i'm correct, but your root issue is entirely different, for which i believe you should ask another question. but my advice before you do that, read more about the different types of apps you can have on the facebook platform, and how they integrate with facebook